# Use Loader class within a hook in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, view, loader

I have this function that is in a hook:

```
public function checkIfLogged() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('logged') ){
        $this->CI->load->view('common/home');
        exit;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `$this->CI->load->view('common/home');` doesn't actually load the template file at all. Is there any resons why?

I am using a post_controller_constructor hook.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Dumb question : did you check if session class is loaded and if session userdata doesnt exist ?

Comment: Hehe,  yeah. Thanks for the comment, but he session is definitely loaded, I sorted that here two minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512799/why-i-cant-use-sessions-in-a-codeigniter-hook :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pre_system**

Called very early during system execution. Only the benchmark and hooks class have been loaded at this point. No routing or other processes have happened.

**pre_controller**

Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done.

**post_controller_constructor**

Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.

**post_controller**

Called immediately after your controller is fully executed.

**display_override**

Overrides the _display() function, used to send the finalized page to the web browser at the end of system execution. This permits you to use your own display methodology. Note that you will need to reference the CI superobject with $this->CI =& get_instance() and then the finalized data will be available by calling $this->CI->output->get_output()

**cache_override**

Enables you to call your own function instead of the _display_cache() function in the output class. This permits you to use your own cache display mechanism.

**post_system**

Called after the final rendered page is sent to the browser, at the end of system execution after the finalized data is sent to the browser.

so

i think the one you are looking for is **display_override**

but you can also take a look here [Does CodeIgniter have to load view in the final step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892941/does-codeigniter-have-to-load-view-in-the-final-step)

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem was your use of `exit`. When you load a view, its output is added to the Output class (`system/core/Output.php`). The final view data is then sent (echoed) to the browser by the line `$OUT->_display();` found in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`.

Since you tossed the `exit` in there, the script stops, and that display method is never called.

I don't really know what you're trying to do with this hook (it looks like displaying a specified page if a user is logged out or something), but the quickest solution would be to return the output of the view and echo it directly from the hook.

```
public function checkIfLogged() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('logged') ){
        exit($this->CI->load->view('common/home', null, true));
    }
}
```

I'd discourage the use of the `display_override` hook, because your entire controller's code will run before the hook even has a chance to check the particular session data (and it's possible that your controller might even overwrite that session data, giving unexpected results).

You may even consider using a base controller (MY_Controller) instead of a hook. It may be more suitable depending on your situation / desired functionality.

Comment: That's makes perfect sense.  Thanks for such a good answer.  Very in depth.  I just used a redirect so instead of loading that view,  it just redirects to a page with a controller that uses that view.  Thanks though :)

Comment: That works. I'd recommend looking into a base controller, still, if you're unfamiliar. They're extremely useful.