# Stop execution after call $this->load->view()

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, How could we stop the execution after load a view?

I have tried this

```
function index() {
    $this->load->view('myView');
    die();

    //do not execute next code
}
```

but it resulting blank screen.

Comment: what error are you getting? does your file "myView.php" is in the root of view folder?

Comment: try something like `function remap() { $this->index(); }`

Comment: I usually create `_render(){}` function and put all view loads in there, so it should work without problem.

Comment: @NiloySaha, I'm sorry i have changed my question, hope you could help it.

Comment: what is in `myView.php`

Comment: @dianuj an HTML box with some message within,

Comment: What is in the `source` of page if you see by `ctrl+u`

Comment: What about `return`  ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way.

```
echo $this->load->view('myView', '', TRUE);
    die();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Alternatively we could write `die($this->load->view('myView', '', TRUE));`

Comment: [I've described why you can't `exit` after loading a view here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512900/use-loader-class-within-a-hook-in-codeigniter/16532287#16532287)

Comment: thumps up for the info that the data can be returned as string in in view load

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm late but I came across this whilst searching to find out if loading a view stops execution but apparently it does not.

It might still be useful to someone so... To stop execution after loading a view, you can just return:

```
$this->load->view('myView');
return;
```

This will not stop PHP (unlike `die()` or `exit()`), CI will load the view as it normally would and any following code will not run.

Comment: Yes this is very useful. I've tried @Sefus solution but it did not work. This worked like a charm :) Thank you

Comment: This works for me.Where in latest version `die()` Isn't work .

Comment: `return` works, but it's not enough if one is using a custom method in the controller method to send the output. E.g., I have a `response()` method that I'm calling in the controller method. I output a JSON which varies depending on the situation. So I have multiple calls to the `response()`. Execution should stop in the `response()`, otherwise I'll have to `return` after each `response()` call. This would not be practical. I manually echo the output in the `response()` and then `exit`. Now, I can freely use the `response()` in any controller method without the use of `return`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question. After lots of googling, I am currently throwing my error pages this way:

### helpers/X.php

```
function load_404_page_then_die($obj)
{
    $obj->output->set_status_header(404);
    load_page_with_great_races_sidebar($obj, 'errors/html/error_404_custom');
    send_view_then_die($obj);
}

function send_view_then_die($obj)
{
    // Force the CI engine to render the content generated until now    
    $obj->CI =& get_instance();
    $obj->CI->output->_display();

    die();
}
```

### controllers/X.php

```
$data['volunteer'] = $this->volunteer_model->get_volunteer_by_id($volunteer_id_and_text) OR load_404_page_then_die($this);
```

The other way to do it is to use "return" while in a public method of the controller. However, this results in code that doesn't fit on one line, and you can't use this technique while in a private method of the controller or while in a helper file.

### controllers/X.php

```
$data['volunteer'] = $this->volunteer_model->get_volunteer_by_id($volunteer_id_and_text);
if ( empty($data['volunteer']) )
{
    load_404_page($this);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call load->view at the end of your controller method. If you stop execution then other parts of the theme will not be loaded. Your view file contents will only be rendered. You can use this method for ajax calls where you do not want any thing else should be rendered except what you want to render as out put of ajax call.

Comment: I'm sorry i have changed my question, hope you could help it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You can't, because Codeigniter have to run other script after you load a view, such as CI need to call `display()` method from `Output` class to render your view. In your case(if i'm not misunderstanding), I suggest you to just load your view at the end of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I know am very late. But here is the solution. it has to be outputted to _display. Just incase if any newbie faces the same issue then this would be ideal i feel.

```
$this->load->view('myView');
$this->output->_display();
die;
```