# Codeigniter loads a empty page

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

I'm facing a strange problem with CI:

After my view is loaded, I select an option in the form and send the request. My backend handles it and sends me a response. In case of an error I catch the Exception and want to load the same view but with a error message on it.

The problem is I get an empty page. When I place a `die()` command in the last line of the view, I can see the page with my error message. If I place the `die()` command directly after
 `$this->load->view($template, $vars)`

in the controller I get an empty page, the same way as on beginning without any `die()` commands. 
I've set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors is on, but no error occurs.

What's going wrong here?

I appreciate any kind of help in advance!

Cheers!
naptoon

Comment: add your controller function to the question

Comment: Please add some code here. What is the URL you are trying? Help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put `exit()` or `die()` directly after `$this->load->view()`, unless you return the view's output using the third parameter.

I've outlined why here: [Use Loader class within a hook in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512900/use-loader-class-within-a-hook-in-codeigniter/16532287#16532287)

Comment: I only read this answer when I found out the problem. Loading a view doesn't immediately output it to the browser - which is also good to know in combination with echo in between.